# how to parse error json returned by a 422 response?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

this is the response when using fiddler

```
HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
Server: nginx/1.9.4
Date: Thu, 25 Feb 2016 18:03:15 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 31
Connection: close
Status: 422 Unprocessable Entity
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

{"error":"username is invalid"}
```

this is my code to call web service and i used retrofit web service I can parse data when success(code 201) but when code (422) I could not find error message

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<UserRegister>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<UserRegister> call, Response<UserRegister> response) {

        if (response.isSuccess()) {
            txt_pressure.setText("username:  " + response.body().username);
        } else {
            // how to parse error when 422
        }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<UserRegister> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Network error has occurred. Retry again...",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: You will get this message in `onFailure`. Are you able to see the toast message when 422 code is returned?

Comment: No,when debugging onFailure wasnot called @Rohit5k2

Comment: Does `onResponse` gets called?

Comment: yes its called but i did not find error message in the body or raw or errorbody but when using fiddler i found the message as described in the question @Rohit5k2

Comment: Probably because error message can't be parse into `Response<UserRegister>`

Comment: i passed parameter called error in the class UserRegister but i didnot get the error @Rohit5k2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
if(response.code() == 422) {
    //do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: Hello, I am using Retrofit2 in android to do API calls, and when API returns Error i.e. "Mobile number is already taken" than this error comes with status code 422, and Retrofit consider it as Error so it redirect response to the onError and i want that response in onNext, so how can i achieve this ? please help.

Comment: @RaviVaniya I was working with Retrofit two years ago :) Ask your questions as a new question on the SO and I am sure somebody will help you

Answer (score 0):

if(responseCode==422){

```
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getErrorStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            Log.e("res--"+response);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

From retrofit documentation, you have to use:

`Response.errorBody()` - The raw response body of an unsuccessful response

Here it is the doc:

http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html#errorBody--